# Can we read encrypted snapshot after coping to another region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

Can we read the data in EBS Volume in region ap-southeast-2 after copping? Because the KMS Key A, which is the key we use to encrypt and decrypt, is currently in eu-west-2.

[image]

Comment: A very useful solution for your requirement is KMS [Multi-Region Keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/multi-region-keys-overview.html). Note though that you cannot convert existing single region keys to Multi-Region.  Please provide some additional context to finetune the solution.

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-copy-snapshot.html#ebs-incremental-copy "When you copy a snapshot, you can encrypt the copy or you can specify a KMS key that is different than the original, and the resulting copied snapshot uses the new KMS key. "